# Programmatically read internet explorer cookies

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, cookies, base64

I'm trying to create a piece of software (C++ with Qt) that would search some data into cookies of my website.

I found the WinAPI function named [InternetGetCookie(szURL, NULL, lpszData, &dwSize)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385326%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but when I want to show the result I have something like this:

```
__utma=166311972.1573129762.1302471948.1313050619.1313050781.24; __utmz=166
311972.1302471948.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); kk_als=ZmNk
YzE4MGIzYWQwMDI3Mzc0ZTkwMDQ2MWMwMGM5MTUjIzgxLjI0Ny4zNi4xNTcjI05PX1BBUkVOVCMjMTMw
MjQ3MTk1MiMjLyMjTk9fUkVGRVJFUiMjTk9fT1BUX0lORk8jIzEjIzAjIzAjIzAjIzAjIzEjIzE%3D
```

It looks like base64 but I can't find what I want.

Somebody know how to read this cookie ?

PS: sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found.

When IE is in protected mode you can't see all the cookies with "InternetGetCookie"

To solve this problem there is an other function:

```
    HRESULT IEGetProtectedModeCookie(
  __in     LPCWSTR lpszURL,
  __in     LPCWSTR lpszCookieName,
  __inout  LPWSTR pszCookieData,
  __inout  DWORD *pcchCookieData,
  __in     DWORD dwFlags
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

InternetGetCookie return a string with all cookies for a given url separated by semicolons. Each cookie in the string is in the format name=data

Comment: OK, in fact when IE is in protected mode I can't access to all the cookies. I have to use this function: